# ggplot: plot multiple answers coded as dummy variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

R and ggplot newbie here.
I'm trying to create some meaningful plots for a data frame representing answers to a questionnaire in which some people gave multiple answers of the sort:

*what meat do you like (check all that apply):
1.fish;
2.pork*

for other questions there's only one choice:

*do you drink beer? seldom / often / never*

Since there are multiple answers, they have been coded as dummy variables: eat.fish has value 1 for a positive answer, 0 otherwise and the same for eat.pork. The data frame looks like this:

```
pork<-c(0,1,0,1,1)
id<-c(1:5)
sex<-c("m","m","f","f","f")
eat.fish<-c(1,1,0,0,1)
eat.pork<-c(0,1,0,1,1)
drink.beer<-c("often","seldom","never","seldom","never")
df<-data.frame(id,sex,eat.fish,eat.pork,drink.beer)
```

Now, for a categorical variable like drink.beer, I know how to get some meaningful plots with ggplot2:

```
qplot(data=df, drink.beer, fill=drink.beer)
```

and

```
qplot(data=df, drink.beer, fill=drink.beer)+facet_wrap(~sex)
```

but I would like to to the same for the pork and fish variables but I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could recode the variables

```
df$eat.pork2 <- ifelse(df$eat.pork == 1, "eat_pork", "dont_eat_pork")
qplot(data=df, eat.pork2, fill=eat.pork2)
```

Or if you want to combine pork and fish into a single variable

```
df$eat <- ifelse(df$eat.pork == 1 & df$eat.fish == 1, "eat_pork_fish",
             ifelse( df$eat.pork == 1 & df$eat.fish == 0, "eat_pork_only", 
             ifelse( df$eat.pork == 0 & df$eat.fish == 1, "eat_fish_only",                         
             "neither_pork_fish")))

qplot(data=df, eat, fill=eat)+facet_wrap(~sex)
qplot(data=df, eat, fill=eat)
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't help me in fact, as it introduces the "dont_eat" value for each of the variables. It's as if for the beer category I wouldn't have a cumulative "often", "seldom", "never" barchart, but 3 different ones, "often" vs "dont_drink", "seldom" vs "dont_drink" and "never" vs "dont_drink". So what I need it to get rid of the 0 values (or the "dont_eat" ones).

Comment: So are you trying to collapse pork and fish into a single variable? You could do that with a series of ifelse statements.

Answer (score 0):

Now your `eat.pork` and `eat.fish` variables are numeric. You can convert them to factor variables inside the `qplot` function like this:

```
qplot(data=df, as.factor(eat.pork), fill=as.factor(eat.pork)) + facet_wrap(~sex)
```

You can do the same for the `eat.fish` variable. When you want to combine the `eat.pork` and `eat.fish` variables into one variable, see the answer of matt_k for an instruction how to do this.